# o365 graph api creating a reference attachment

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to add a reference attachment to a conversation post using the graph API (beta) but I get an internal server error without any further hints to whats going wrong.

Tried both endpoints, but getting the same result:
POST /groups/{id}/threads/{id}/posts/{id}/attachments
POST /groups/{id}/conversations/{id}/threads/{id}/posts/{id}/attachments

Has anyone got this working?

Comment: There isn't enough information here to go on. Please edit your question to include a minimum viable code sample showing how you're calling the API, the payload your sending, and the exact error message you're receiving back.

Comment: +1 to Marc. What are you trying to do here. Upload a file to an existing thread?
It looks like you are trying to combine conversation thread operations with message attachment operations.  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/group_update_thread